# oracle sql - how to get record with biggest value from certail range

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to query DB to find records that returns HISTOLOGY_NUM that:

1. has a column with value: ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'His: In Queue'
2. and AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID column WHICH HAS ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'His: In Queue' HAS the biggest value among the same the same numbers of HISTOLOGY_NUM

SO far I have a query which returns HISTOLOGY_NUM  which has the biggest value of AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID  but i don't know how to incorporate into it that it needs to have ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'His: In Queue' :

```
SELECT a.HISTOLOGY_NUM, a.AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID

FROM V_HISTOLOGY_ACTIVITY a

INNER JOIN (

    SELECT HISTOLOGY_NUM, MAX(AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID) AS AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID

    FROM V_HISTOLOGY_ACTIVITY

    GROUP BY HISTOLOGY_NUM 

) b ON a.HISTOLOGY_NUM = b.HISTOLOGY_NUM
```

Comment: does ACTIVITY_TYPE belongs to V_HISTOLOGY_ACTIVITY???

Comment: yes it belongs to V_HISTOLOGY_ACTIVITY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
SELECT a.HISTOLOGY_NUM, a.AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID

FROM V_HISTOLOGY_ACTIVITY a,(

    SELECT HISTOLOGY_NUM, MAX(AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID) AS AP_RCVL_ACTIVITY_ID

    FROM V_HISTOLOGY_ACTIVITY

    GROUP BY HISTOLOGY_NUM 

) b where 
a.HISTOLOGY_NUM = b.HISTOLOGY_NUM and a.ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'His: In Queue'
```